# Setting cursor position to beginning of next input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the position of the cursor to the beginning of the next input element. For some reason, it is setting it one character in from the left instead of at the beginning.

I am trying to do this only when the user is at the end of the input they are in and presses the right arrow key.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UTk2R/)

**HTML**

```
<p class="after">
    <input type="text" value="something1 this is something else" name="AnswerData0" />
    <input type="text" value="something2" name="AnswerData1" />
    <input type="text" value="something3" name="AnswerData2" />
    <input type="text" value="something4" name="AnswerData3" />
</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".after input[name^='AnswerData']").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);        
        $this.attr("contenteditable", "true")
            .css({
                "border": "1px solid #000"
            });
    });

    $("input[name^='AnswerData']").keyup(function(event){
        var currentVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr("value", currentVal);
    });

    // handle using "right" key at the end of a span
    $("input[name^='AnswerData']").keydown(function(event){
        if (event.which == 39 && $(this).getCursorPosition() == $(this).val().length) {
            $(this).next("input[name^='AnswerData']").selectRange(0, 0);
//          alert($(this).getCursorPosition());
        }
    });

$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    if(!end){
        end = start;
    }
    return this.each(function() {
        var range;

        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};

$.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    var pos = 0;
    if('selectionStart' in el) {
        pos = el.selectionStart;
    } else if('selection' in document) {
        el.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
        pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Have I missed something in my jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`if (event.which == 39 && $(this).getCursorPosition() == ($(this).val().length -1)) {`

Comment: The problem isn't detecting that I'm at the end of the <span>, its setting the cursor to the beginning of the next <span> - `$(this).next("input[name^='AnswerData']").selectRange(0, 0);` The if statement you refer to, just detects when to set this.